# Getting argument names as passed by the user in OO systems

Tags: r

I've been experimenting with the R7 OO system.

Getting an argument name - as it is passed by the user - appears to work differently in R7 versus 'normal functions'. I also found that S3 acts like R7 in this regard:

```r
library(R7)
library(rlang)

my_function <- function(x) {
  x |> enquo() |> get_expr()
}

cat <- "dog"
my_function(cat)
#> cat

my_generic <- new_generic("my_generic", c("x"))

method(my_generic, class_character) <-
  function(x) {
    x |> enquo() |> get_expr()
  }

my_generic(cat)
#> [1] "dog"

my_s3_generic <- function(x) {
  UseMethod("my_s3_generic")
}

my_s3_generic.character <- function(x) {
  x |> enquo() |> get_expr()
}

my_s3_generic(cat)
#> [1] "dog"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Suppose I wanted to get `cat` instead. How would I do this in OO systems like R7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround [here](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/issues/303#issuecomment-460938400), as well as the reason why it doesn't work [here](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/issues/553#issuecomment-401852105):

> The first argument of S3 methods is always evaluated and so cannot be captured.

The solution is to modify the *generic*:

```r
my_s3_generic <- function(x) {
  ex <- tidy_eval(enquo(x))
  UseMethod("my_s3_generic", ex)
}
```